# Did Mad-eye Moody lose a buttock?

Tags: harry-potter

Did he lose a buttock by igniting his pants with his wand?

> 'Dont put your wand there, boy!' roared Moody.'What if it ignited? Better wizards than you have lost buttocks, you know!'
>   'Who d'you know who's lost a buttock?'the violet-haired woman asked Mad-eye interestingly.
>   'Never you mind, you just keep your wand out of your back pocket!' growled Mad-eye.

This seems like he spoke from experience

Comment: I always took it to be one of those cautionary statements adults make, despite not actually knowing anybody that the same thing has happened to, then when he was actually asked for examples he brushed off the question because he didn't have an answer.

Comment: What a half-assed question :|

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The *implication* is that it was Mad-Eye Moody who lost a buttock, yes, but nowhere in the series does it explicitly state this as fact.

The other candidate for losing a buttock would have been Fred Weasley:

> ‘You die,’ said Ron simply. ‘Fred and George tried to get me to make [an Unbreakable Vow] when I was about five. I nearly did, too, I was holding hands with Fred and everything when Dad found us. He went mental,’ said Ron, with a reminiscent gleam in his eyes. ‘Only time I’ve ever seen Dad as angry as Mum. **Fred reckons his left buttock has never been the same since**.’
>   <sub>*Half-Blood Prince* - page 305 - Bloomsbury - chapter 16, *A Very Frosty Christmas*</sub>

However, this language implies that Fred retained his buttock, even if it didn't remain in its original condition.

I still err on the side of Moody being the one to have completely lost a buttock. Moody is undoubtedly a better wizard than Tonks is a witch, who is in turn a better witch than Fred Weasley is a wizard, purely through experience's sake at the very least. So if a better wizard than Tonks has lost a buttock, my money's on Moody's bum being the one to have taken the hit.

Comment: I took it to mean Fred had received a hearty paddling from his Dad.

Comment: @MajorStackings -- Me too, but as it's the only other mention of a buttock injury in the entire series, I thought I should note it. :D

Comment: But now I have to wonder if a missing buttock accounted for Moody's special broom. Perhaps he couldn't get a grip on the standard version.

Comment: @MajorStackings First, ew. Second, probably so, the ick factor aside. :)

Comment: I think you give too much credit to Fred's ability to say things that aren't 90%+ sarcastic. "Fred reckons" and "This is what happened" are two things out of sync.

Comment: @DVK - I was being tongue-in-cheek about Fred.

Comment: @MajorStackings You might want to turn the comment about the recumbent broom into an answer, or perhaps add it to Slytherincess' answer.

Comment: @SQB I posed your suggestion to Slytherincess. If she doesn't incorporate it into her answer, I probably will.

Comment: @MajorStackings so, go ahead!

Comment: If I'm interpreting your "a better wizard than Tonks" line correctly, you've made a slight error: Mad-Eye said that to Harry, not Tonks.

Comment: Tonks also said "Who do you know that's lost a buttock?". If Tonks lost Moody's buttock then why is she asking?

Answer (score 7):

I took it as a generic warning - like when adults tell children not to make faces because if the wind changes they will stay like it.

Comment: Basically what Anthony Grist said in his comment above, but still a good possibility.

Comment: Ahem - yes good spot! That'll teach me not to read the full page before replying!