# Harry Potter Universe - Why not attach a wand to a contraption around hand?

Tags: harry-potter

Like in the Assassin's Creed games, why wouldn't a wizard attach his wand to a contraption tied around his wrist that would be retractable?

This would serve three purposes:

1. The wand is always at the ready to flick out and cast spells
2. The wand would never be out of reach, like from falling on the ground or suspended in midair
3. I would think it would a little harder to disarm said wizard.

Comment: You mean like a wii strap?

Comment: @SJuan76 - Better than tucking it in your waistband... Ouch!

Comment: @Richard You mean [tucking it in your back pocket](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34383/did-mad-eye-moody-lose-a-buttock). Never misquote a meme ;-)

Comment: I'd much rather blast off a buttock than the alternative...

Comment: Replace the word `wand` with `gun`. Now you have your answer ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Well, apart from complications that would arise from relying on a spring loaded contraption to supply your wand (which can fail, be sabotaged, and rust over), there would at least be a minor inconvenience depending on any particular person's ratio of wand length to length of forearm.

I haven't done any primary research on either variables, but the [Harry Potter wiki page for wands](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Wand) claims that wands vary in length from 7 to 18 inches, though most are within 9 to 14 inches. Additionally, there is [this](http://www.censusatschool.ca/data-results/2006-07/length-of-forearm/) Canadian school survey on the average length of student forearms, which I have copied below (converting from cm to inches, and narrowing the field to Hogwarts eligible ages for succinctness).

[image: data table]

So it can be gathered that, although certainly *some* wizards *may* benefit from having such a contraption, rather a lot of them wouldn't even be able to fit their wands against their forearms.

Comment: I love the fact that someone conducted such a detailed survey about the average length of schoolchildren's forearms. You may have stumbled upon the best/only use of such information.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been useful, though I would not favour it. What if it fails, imagine not being able to access the wand in an emergency situation because the magic is faulty (maybe your enemy messed with it beforehand?).

Myself, I prefer a wandholster fastened to the forearm. For some reason the idea appeals more to me. Fandom often uses them, those wandholsters are also often protected against summoning charms, etc. Quite ingenious.

Frankly with how unsafe most wands are kept its a wonder there aren't more wands that snap accidentally (like Ron's). Just imagine putting it in your jeans pocket and sitting down.